# can't connect to wi fi

Tags: wireless

I have a problem with connecting to a wi-fi point after my laptop sleep. only after rebooting the laptop connects to the wi-fi.
I couldn't find the answers on Google.
Please tell me how to solve everything
I did my best but nothing worked.
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN [8086:4060]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command. Is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: ```~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN [8086:4060]
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
 Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases this happens.

As a workaround instead of rebooting you can run in a terminal

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

You an also report it as a bug.

Comment: unfortunately did not help (